# TeamCity schedule trigger with additional VCS rules

Tags: svn, triggers, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I'm trying to configure a Schedule Trigger  in **TeamCity 7.1.4** which will trigger the build every day at 7 AM, but only if there were commits to the project's folder since the last build.

I've configured the schedule trigger thus:

[image]

with these VCS trigger rules:

```
-:.
+:root=SVN_Branch_builds:/ermc/**
+:root=SVN_Branch_builds:/development/source/Endava/ER/ERCommerce/**
```

1. remove all rules
2. add rule only if there were commits to the VCS folder
3. add rule only if there were commits to the VCS folder

(`SVN_Branch_builds` is the name of the VCS root).

However, the trigger doesn't work at all. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally when 'Trigger build only if there are pending changes' is checked & trigger rules are defined it should work. Not sure on exact problem here as seems like you have not got any errors.

Once you goto `'Build Configuration Home' -> Settings` , do you see your rules defined & next scheduled time is correct?.

As an alternative way, you can try with configuring  settings using cron-like expressions http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Configuring+Schedule+Triggers to schedule daily.

Select `Trigger build: as advanced(cron expression)` from drop-down & you can put time trigger based on your need.